# Как переделать дата-атрибуты выпадающего списка для ссылок?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть [демо интернет-магазин](http://motors.likemedia.by/product-category/on-water/lodochnye-motory/suzuki/) в котором есть фильтр сортировки товаров боковой панели
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сейчас сортировка товаров работает по алфавиту (в прямую и обратную сторону) и цене в выпадающем списке в одну сторону. Я же стремлюсь сделать так, чтобы цена была реализована точно также, как и алфавит с помощью ссылки, а не выпадающего списка (как видно на рисунке и сайте), но в отличие от списка в ссылке не прописывается `&orderby=price` 
Как это можно поправить? Привожу код:

```
$product_order = array();
         $product_order['menu_order'] = "Default";
         $product_order['price']     = "Price";
         $product_order_key = !empty($params['orderby']) ? $params['orderby'] : 'menu_order';
         $product_sort_key =  !empty($params['product_sort']) ? $params['product_sort'] : 'ASC';
         $product_sort_key = strtolower($product_sort_key);
?>
    <div class="sort-param sort-param-order">
         <div class="custom-select">
           <div class="select-title"><?php echo $product_order[$product_order_key] ?></div>
           <ul class="select-list"></ul>
           <select name="param-count">
               <option data-href="menu_order" selected value="menu_order">
                  <?php echo $product_order['menu_order'] ?>
               </option>
               <option data-href="price" value="price">
                  <?php echo $product_order['price'] ?>
               </option>
            </select>
          </div><!--/ .custom-select-->
     </div>
<div class="order-param-button">
         <a title="<?php esc_html_e('Click to order products', MAD_BASE_TEXTDOMAIN) ?>" data-href="price" data-sort="<?php echo esc_attr($product_sort_key) ?>&orderby=price" class="order-param-<?php echo sanitize_html_class($product_sort_key) ?>" href="javascript:void(0)"> <?php echo $product_order['price'] ?></a>
     </div><!--/ .order-param-button-->
     <div class="order-param-button">
         <a title="<?php esc_html_e('Click to order products', MAD_BASE_TEXTDOMAIN) ?>" data-sort="<?php echo esc_attr($product_sort_key) ?>" class="order-param-<?php echo sanitize_html_class($product_sort_key) ?>"  href="javascript:void(0)"> Алфавит</a>
     </div><!--/ .order-param-button-->
```

p.s. сейчас цена и алфавит считаются только в одну сторону правильно, а при повторном на них клике все сбивается в кучу и фильтр почему-то начинает считаться для всех товаров

Comment: у вас сайт неподъёмный, подгружается у меня где-то с полминуты, лично у меня терпения не хватит что-либо проверить, на главной странице только насчитал 71 скрипт js и 49 файлов css. А приведённый вами код практически ничего не говорит, по нему полностью не понять как реализована сортировка товаров. Вам срочно нужно работать над оптимизацией своего проекта, а не над внедрением новых фич!

Comment: ещё я заметил, что вы переделываете свой уже работающий сайт с CMS bitrix на CMS WordPress. На чём вы основывались, выбирая новую CMS для своего ресурса?

Comment: @Blacknife у вас есть, что по вопросу ответить или будете рассуждать не по существу?

Comment: я ни в коем случае не рассуждаю, я вам дал один совет-рекомендацию и задал один вопрос. Если вам не хочется ни прислушиваться ни отвечать на вопросы - мы от этого не страдаем. Успехов!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Вася
В общем посмотрел код, который генерирует AJAX запросы у Вас на сайте... Он живет в скрипте [Скрипт сбора данных для виджета сортировки](http://motors.likemedia.by/wp-content/themes/flatastic/inc/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/js/woof-front.js?ver=2.5.2)
Весь код скрипта здесь публиковать не буду, ибо там ох...
В строке 88 начинается сбор данных при клике по стрелочкам в Вашем виджете.

Проблема кроется в том, что параметр сортировки 
**orderby** вы не передаете

Вставьте перед 105 строкой(**mad_woof_ajax_page_num = 1;**) 
Вот это и будет вам счастье...

---

**mad_woof_current_values.orderby = $this.data().href || '';**

Comment: вот только срабатывает этот финт 1 раз, а при дальнейших кликах, что на цену, что на алфавит уже какая-то неразбериха идет - все товары в одну кучу сортируются - не знаете в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Знаю у вас если не передовая параметра her то по алфавиту сортировка идет

Comment: не совсем понятно, что за параметр her и где я могу увидеть разницу? в адресной строке отличий, кроме `orderby=price` не вижу

Comment: Извините не her а href и увидеть можно в девтулзах

Comment: а где именно это показывается там, на какой закладке и в какой момент - нажатия на кнопку? - не знаю как это можно увидеть

Comment: во вкладке network? - пока не нахожу как это можно увидеть

Comment: не могу обнаружить где http://i053.radikal.ru/1604/fe/ea81cfeaf980.png

Comment: насколько понимаю при первом клике taxonomies и product_cat есть, а уже при повторном вызове - нет `shortcode=mad_woof_products+taxonomies%3Dproduct_cat%3A3505+is_ajax`